# Export data to PDF in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to export a list to PDF in MVC4.

Recently saw this code which exports list to Excel.

```
public ActionResult ExportDataExcel()
    {


        var y= TempData["List"]; //list


        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = y;
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Exam_Email_Report.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return RedirectToAction("TestReport", "Test");
    }
```

I was wondering how to export list to PDF. Please give me some pointers that could help me.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, PDF as not as simple as you showed. The grid is generating a XML or CSV file that Excel can read without issues. For PDF, you must a PDF library such as iTextSharp, generate the PDF on the server, then return a FileAction to be downloaded.

Comment: @EddiePaz Oh! Ok. I'll check iTextSharp then. Thank you for your reply.